# public file name encoding on windows

Tags: files

I have to deploy a drupal 7 site built on Linux on a windows machine. Some (image) files are referenced via the public file mechanism. Some of them have special characters in their names, encoded in UTF-8 (AFAIK)

Files directly referenced are correctly handled by apache, for example:
`http://localhost/lv/sites/all/themes/bizz/images/1.pr%C3%A9sentation.jpg`
But the ones that are referenced via drupal public files cannot be accessed; for example `http://localhost/lv/?q=sites/default/files/styles/large/public/2.teint%C3%A9_60_380X448_2.png&itok=RvL-USAY` returns a 404

The file exists in the filesystem (as `2.teinté_60_380X448_2.png` and as `2.teint├®_60_380X448_2.png` [that was the name I got in the zip export file]) I tried `2.teintÃ©_60_380X448_2.png` (UTF-8 as latin-1) too, but without more luck.

Is there a way to get drupal finds these files without editing all posts ?

Comment: Do you check if /sites/default/files are given read and modify permission for IIS_IUSRS e.g. running C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Drupal>icacls sites\default\files /grant BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS:(OI)(CI)(M)

Comment: It runs under apache

Comment: @Bastein Durel sorry I read your first sentence and automatically thinks that you are having problem with files on IIS under windows machine

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong, `2.teintÃ©_60_380X448_2.png` works, now I only have to write a script that converts all filenames to utf8, and use it as latin-1, great :/